# How to get in javascript, filtered records from simple json file server side with ajax and no database?

Tags: javascript, json, filter

Its possible to get from json file on server, filtered records without a database installed on server side?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it very easily by creating your own filter in javascript. Read the file records in memory and return the records after filtering. example of a simple filter is like :

```js
let data = [
         {name:"a", age:20},
         {name:"b", age:20},
         {name:"c", age:20}
 ]

 let filter = {name:"b"};

 //code at server --
 var filterData = data.filter(row=>{
       if(!filter){
            return true;
       }
       for(var key in filter){
           return !(row[key] !== filter[key]);
       }
      return true;
 })
 
 console.log("filterData>>>",filterData );
```

you can make your filter more smart as you need.

Comment: Thanks, but if file is "big" doing client side is slow. I will like to filter server side

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define "database".

You can store the store the data in a JSON file, then have some server side code read that file and filter it according to whatever you put in an HTTP request, then return the remaining data.

That wouldn't use any off-the-shelf software with "database" in the name … but it would be a database.

Comment: Thanks thats what i'm search. Do you know if there is something lite for do this?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." (but it is probably trivial to write something in whatever server side language you like)